# Checkboxes Spring MVC form binding error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a student class with one to many association with subject class :

```
public class Student implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -779930820340758193L;
    private int studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private List<Subject> subjectList;


    public Student(int studentId, String studentName, List<Subject> subjectList) {
        super();
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.subjectList = subjectList;
    }
    public Student() {
    }
    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
    public List<Subject> getSubjectList() {
        return subjectList;
    }
    public void setSubjectList(List<Subject> subjectList) {
        this.subjectList = subjectList;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [studentId=" + studentId + ", studentName="
                + studentName + ", subjectList=" + subjectList + "]";
    }


}
```

Subject:

```
public class Subject implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7135393884889475409L;
    private int subjectId;
    private String subjectName;

    public Subject(int subjectId, String subjectName) {
        super();
        this.subjectId = subjectId;
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }
    public int getSubjectId() {
        return subjectId;
    }
    public void setSubjectId(int subjectId) {
        this.subjectId = subjectId;
    }
    public String getSubjectName() {
        return subjectName;
    }
    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + subjectId;
        result = prime * result
                + ((subjectName == null) ? 0 : subjectName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Subject other = (Subject) obj;
        if (subjectId != other.subjectId)
            return false;
        if (subjectName == null) {
            if (other.subjectName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!subjectName.equals(other.subjectName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Subject [subjectId=" + subjectId + ", subjectName="
                + subjectName + "]";
    }

}
```

My controller returns a list of all subjects and also the subjects enrolled by the student, so that they are checked by default in the view.

Controller:

```
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      List<Subject> allList = new ArrayList<Subject>();
      allList.add(new Subject(1,"English"));
      allList.add(new Subject(2,"Maths"));
      allList.add(new Subject(3,"Science"));
      allList.add(new Subject(4,"Social"));
      allList.add(new Subject(5,"Tamil")); 

      List<Subject> enrolledList = new ArrayList<Subject>();
      enrolledList.add(new Subject(1,"English")); 
      enrolledList.add(new Subject(3,"Science"));

      Student student = new Student(1,"SRI",enrolledList);
      model.addAttribute("student", student);
      model.addAttribute("availableList", allList);
      return "home";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "save" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute Student student , ModelMap model){
       System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>"+student);
       model.addAttribute("finalStudent", student); 
       return "success";
   }
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>${student.studentName}</h2>
    <form:form method="POST" action="save" modelAttribute="student">
        <form:checkboxes title="Subjects taken" path="subjectList"
            items="${availableList}" itemLabel="subjectName" element="div" />
        <input type = "submit" value = "Save"/>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

But, on sumbit of this form, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'student' on field 'subjectList': rejected value [Subject [subjectId=1, subjectName=English],Subject [subjectId=3, subjectName=Science]]; codes [typeMismatch.student.subjectList,typeMismatch.subjectList,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [student.subjectList,subjectList]; arguments []; default message [subjectList]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'subjectList'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.sri.test.Subject] for property 'subjectList[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Can someone help me?? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `StringToSubjectConverter` class what convert submitted string to `Subject` object:

```
public class StringToSubjectConverter implements Converter<String, Subject> {
  @Override
  public Subject convert(String s) {
    return ...; // your code to convert from `String` to `Subject`
  }
}
```

And register this converter with Spring Conversion Service:

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />

  <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
      <set>
        <bean class="package.StringToSubjectConverter" />
      </set>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your problem. Here you are trying to bind the String array of your Subject object to List of Subject Object , which is impossible to convert the "String[] subject" to List, here is below value your are getting by using checkboxe

```
"Subject [subjectId=1,subjectName=English]"
```

This format of output is coming after choosing your subject due to overridden of toString method.

And Now , spring internally trying to convert this String or String[]{ in case of mutiple selection}, to your List. Which is impossible to convert , even using the convert() method.

So you have to made logic in your save method to first extract these value from String[] and then set into the list of Subject after creation of Subject from the extracted value.

And then you need to set it into the setter of List method.

This is the below code , which modification of two methods

1) toString of your Subject class

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "subjectId=" + subjectId + ",subjectName="+ subjectName;
}
```

2) save method of HelloController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "save.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute Student student,
        BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>" + student);
    int i = 0;

    List<Subject> lSubjects=new ArrayList<Subject>();
    String[] subjectsInString = request.getParameterValues("subjectList");
    String[] eachSubject=null;
    Subject subject=null;
    int subjectId=0;
    String subjectName=null;

    if (result.hasErrors()) {

        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();
        while (i < fieldErrors.size()) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + fieldErrors.get(i));
            i++;
        }

        for (String subjectInString : subjectsInString) {
            System.out.println(subjectInString);
            eachSubject=subjectInString.split(",");
            for(String value:eachSubject){
                if(value.contains("subjectId"))
                subjectId=Integer.parseInt(value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('=')+1,value.length()));

                if(value.contains("subjectName"))
                subjectName=value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('=')+1,value.length());

                /**/
            }

            subject=new Subject(subjectId, subjectName);
            lSubjects.add(subject);
            //eachSubject
        }
        student.setSubjectList(lSubjects);
        System.out.println("Subject List[ "+student.getSubjectList()+" ]");

    } else {
        model.addAttribute("finalStudent", student);
    }
    return "success";

}
```

I hope this will help you , please let me know if you are facing problem still.